# Numerical integration /w Simpson in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I've created a simple simpson_adaptive method that uses my own simpson method.
My simpson method is correct, but my adaptive method does not seem to work for

```
integral( sin(2*pi*x)² ) ranging from -1 to 1
```

The following code represents the adaptive simpson method.
The parameters stand for the function, [a,b] being the interval for the integral and e being the precision.

```
function I = simpson_adaptief(f,a,b,e)

    I1 = simpson(f,a,b,2);
    I2 = simpson(f,a,b,4);

    if (abs(I1-I2)<e)
        I = I2;
    else
        I = simpson_adaptief(f,a,(a+b)/2,e) + simpson_adaptief(f,(a+b)/2,b,e);    
    end
end
```

n here being the amount of parts the function is being split into.

```
function I = simpson(f,a,b,n)
    h = (b-a)/(n);
    p=0;
    q=0;
    for k=1:2:(n-1)
        x=a+h*k;
        p=p+f(x);
    end
    for k=2:2:(n-1)
        x=a+h*k;
        q=q+f(x);
    end
    I = h/3*(f(a)+f(b)+4*p+2*q);
end
```

Do you guys have any suggestions on what the possible cause of the problem could be?
Other functions seem to work.

EDIT: I think it has something to do with my `if abs(I1-I2)<e`. When I change it to `abs(I1-I2)>e`, it works, as my program then does the recursion step first.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be able to help, but it's unclear exactly what the problem is.  You said which function it doesn't work for, but it's unclear in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: @Fletch The answer to the integration sin(2*pi*x)^2 over [-1,1] is supposed to be 1. When I use my normal simpson method I get 1, but when I use simpson_adaptief I get 3.9994e-032 as a result. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty new to matlab, but is it possible to call for the function you are creating inside that same function file? That is what I see in your simpson_adaptief function

Comment: It's possible to do so (I think that's how recursion works in matlab) My method works for functions like y=exp(x) (a =-1, b=1) and others but it doesn't work for sin(2*pi*x)². 
I think it has something to do with my if "abs(I1-I2)<e

Comment: Okay then. I don't know :/